# How to use aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have data like this in mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "data" : "ARIN",
    "status" : "CLOSED",
    "createdDate" : Date("2020-02-16T17:32:28+07:00")
},
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "source" : "ARIN",
    "status" : "NEW",
    "createdDate" : Date("2020-02-16T17:32:28+07:00")
},
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "data" : "APNIC",
    "status" : "ONPROGRESS",
    "createdDate" : Date("2020-02-17T17:32:28+07:00")
},
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "data" : "RIPE",
    "status" : "NEW",
    "createdDate" : Date("2020-02-17T17:32:28+07:00")
}
```

I want to result like this

```
{
   statusNew : 2,
   statusOnProgress : 1,
   statusClosed : 1
   statusTicketClosedDate1602 : 1,
   statusTicketNewdDate1602 : 1,
   statusTicketOnProgressDate1602 : 0
}
```

I have try use group and cond in mongodb, but to no avail. How can I write this query?

Comment: Use `$lookup` to traverse all the records and use `$facet` for making the result for each of the fields in your result. Lastly use `$count` to count the records based on the required condition. Do some work :p

Comment: Do you mean for every new/progress/close Date you like to get a dedicated field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query,

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
$group: {
    _id: null,
    statusNew: { $sum: { $cond: [{ "$eq": ["$status", "NEW"] }, 1, 0] } },
    statusOnProgress: { $sum: { $cond: [{ "$eq": ["$status", "ONPROGRESS"] }, 1, 0] } },
    statusClosed: { $sum: { $cond: [{ "$eq": ["$status", "CLOSED"] }, 1, 0] } },
    statusTicketClosedDate1602: {
        $sum: {
            $cond: [{
                $and: [{ "$eq": ["$status", "CLOSED"] },
                { "$gte": ["$createdDate", ISODate("2020-02-16T00:00:00Z")] },
                { "$lt": ["$createdDate", ISODate("2020-02-17T00:00:00Z")] }]
            }, 1, 0]
        }
    },
    statusTicketNewdDate1602: {
        $sum: {
            $cond: [{
                $and: [{ "$eq": ["$status", "NEW"] },
                { "$gte": ["$createdDate", ISODate("2020-02-16T00:00:00Z")] },
                { "$lt": ["$createdDate", ISODate("2020-02-17T00:00:00Z")] }]
            }, 1, 0]
        }
    },
    statusTicketOnProgressDate1602: {
        $sum: {
            $cond: [{
                $and: [{ "$eq": ["$status", "ONPROGRESS"] },
                { "$gte": ["$createdDate", ISODate("2020-02-16T00:00:00Z")] },
                { "$lt": ["$createdDate", ISODate("2020-02-17T00:00:00Z")] }]
            }, 1, 0]
        }
    }
}
}])
```